# How to find duplicate strings in string xml android having different id?

Tags: java, android

I want to ask how to find the duplicate string in strings.xml where other string have different id but the content is same. As I am localizing my application. It has more then 5000 strings.

So is their any studio plugin for finding strings id with same content.

```
 <!---Other team member added string--->

<string name="str_checkin_time">Select check-in time</string>
<string name="str_checkin_date">Select check-in date</string>

 <!---Myself added added string--->
<string name="Select_checkin_time">Select check-in time</string>
<string name="Select_checkin_date">Select check-in date</string>
```

I tried to search but i was getting mostly the interview programs to find dupicate string and also i found a studio plugin but I have to do the same thing i.e select the string then search string. I want something which automatically suggest that this string content is duplicate.

Plugin i found is https://github.com/konifar/android-strings-search-plugin

If you know something then please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for trick I done it my self with online tools. I have replaced `</string>` with `</string><br>` so the text get in different line in xml parser.

For parsing xml to I used :

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest2

Then to find duplicate strings from list. I used below website.

http://www.mynikko.com/tools/tool_duplicateremover.html

Then I have only the text which are duplicate and replaced all the strings using refractor in android studio and kept only single ID.

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try [XML Duplicate Remover](https://xml-duplicate-remover.soft112.com/modal-download.html). delete the key name and leave it empty and click show duplicates.
   It will give you a list of what you need. But the list will have all the different values in it mixed together like so:
   [image]
2. Write a scanner that will load the XML and sort the values into buckets.
   Each time you find an existing value print it with the line number.

Comment: I use Mac and the tool is of Windows. But appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Shadow - working for me https://xml-duplicate-remover.soft112.com/modal-download.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be dangerous!

Imagine a situation when you remove duplicates and consequently change the string. The changed string might not fit to views correctly where the previous string is expected (you might have an expectations on the string - lengthiness, meaning, ...). I would suggest proposing a correct naming key convention together with the usage of android string search plugin. It is all about correct strategy.